# Issues seen during compilation of Net::SSLeay on linux and windows

Tags: perl-module

We have downloaded Net::SSLeay module source from cpan and would like to compile it locally and use it. We are facing issues in two situations.

We need your suggestions on couple of items:

1)  We need to use Net::SSLeay module. We have compiled it on Linux x86_64 box using the following statements:
perl Makefile.PL INC=-I”/include" LIBS=-L” /lib"

This generates a Makefile which doesn’t seem to use –lcrypto option. I want to use this option since we are seeing the following error at the runtime:

undefined symbol: X509_EXTENSION_free

From the below link, it appears that we need to include –lcrypto option. Please help us how to include this option. I tried looking into Makefile.pl but could not understand much since I am new to this Makefile.

http://w3facility.org/question/what-is-undefined-symbol-x509_extension_free/

2)  Secondly, while building on Windows, we need to include openssl_path, but INC= and LIBS= doesn’t seem to work. Openssl libraries are already present in a local directory. Please let us know how to include the path with the #perl Makefile.pl option.

Your suggestions will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it may help you, but I had a similar issue with **Net::SSLeay** when trying to install **LWP::Protocol::https** (in my custom path **/root/perl**):

```
debian:~# apt-get install libssl-dev
debian:~# /root/perl/bin/perl -e "use LWP::Protocol::https"
Can't load '/root/perl/lib/site_perl/5.14.2/armv5tejl-linux/auto/Net/SSLeay/SSLeay.so' for module Net::SSLeay: /root/perl/lib/site_perl/5.14.2/armv5tejl-linux/auto/Net/SSLeay/SSLeay.so: undefined symbol: X509_EXTENSION_free at /root/perl/lib/5.14.2/armv5tejl-linux/DynaLoader.pm line 190.
```

As suggested [HERE](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1124123), I solved by manually compiling Net-SSLeay-1.74 in this way:

```
debian:~/.cpan/build/Net-SSLeay-1.74-Zaf3oe# perl Makefile.PL LIBS="-L/root/perl/lib -lssl -lcrypto -lcrypt3" INC="-I/root/perl/include"
debian:~/.cpan/build/Net-SSLeay-1.74-Zaf3oe# make
debian:~/.cpan/build/Net-SSLeay-1.74-Zaf3oe# make install
```

Then it works correctly:

```
debian:~# /root/perl/bin/perl -e "use LWP::Protocol::https"
debian:~#
```